# Windows 7 does not boot after adding a partition

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning

A new partition was made using following steps:

1. Click to open Computer Management.
   If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
2. In the left pane, under Storage, click Disk Management.
3. Right-click an unallocated region on your hard disk, and then click *New Simple Volume*.
4. In the New Simple Volume Wizard, click *Next*.
5. Type the size of the volume you want to create in megabytes (MB) or accept the maximum default size, and then click *Next*.
6. Accept the default drive letter or choose a different drive letter to identify the partition, and then click *Next*.
7. In the Format Partition dialog box, do one of the following:
   If you don't want to format the volume right now, click *Do not format this volume*, and then click *Next*.
   To format the volume with the default settings, click *Next*.
8. Review your choices, and then click *Finish*.

I do not have a windows DVD for recovery or setup.

What should I do?  Can anything be done using boot options or BIOS settings at start up?

Comment: 1) Which error do you get while booting? (The precise text please).   2) Did you add the new partition before or after the OS partition? 3) Is the drive partitioned using MBR or GPT?

Answer (score 0):

Did you accidentally format over either your C: drive partition or the 100MB system partition that Windows uses to boot from?  If so, your only option is going to be to reinstall Windows.  Whether you did erase one of your primary partitions or not, it may be possible to do a repair from the Windows install process, which would prevent you from losing any data that did not get formatted.

Since you said you do not have a Windows DVD, you can download a copy of the DVD iso file here: http://www.mydigitallife.info/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-from-digital-river/

Once downloaded, you can burn yourself a new copy or use the Windows 7 USB tool, available here: http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool

You will still need your own DVD product key to install.  For most PCs, it can be found on the Windows sticker somewhere on the back or bottom of the computer.

Comment: no i haven't partitioned my C: drive i.e my windows drive,

Comment: can i change my active partition option or something like that in bios or boot options

Comment: I'm not aware of any BIOS that can address the partitions.  They always just see the hardware.  You will need something with boot capabilities to do that.  Either a Windows or Linux DVD or USB drive.  Then you can boot from that (via BIOS settings) and inspect/change the partition information.  Do you get any part of the boot process working, or just a blank screen?  If you get any written errors, what do they say?